# Gather function with categorical and corresponding string variable

Tags: r, tidyr

EDIT: I updated this problem with slightly more details in the data frames I'm starting with and hope to produce.

I'm using R, mostly tidyverse functions, to reshape this dataset. Now I need to convert from wide to long, preserving the relationship between a categorical designation and a text-entry string.

**Here's what it looks like:**

```
Name    Skill1 Skill1text   Skill2  Skill2text  Skill3  Skill3text Comm1 Comm2
Will    Yes    "SQL"        No      n/a         Yes     "Dishes"   xyz   zyx
Phil    Yes    "C++"        Yes     "Soup"      No      n/a        123   321
Jill    No     n/a          Yes     "Rice"      Yes     "Painting" abc   cba
```

**I want it to look like this:**

```
Name    SkillName   YesOrNo   Text       Comm1    Comm2
Will    Skill1      Yes       "SQL"      xyz      zyx
Phil    Skill1      Yes       "C++"      123      321
Jill    Skill1      No        n/a        abc      cba
Will    Skill2      No        n/a        xyz      zyx
Phil    Skill2      Yes       "Soup"     123      321
Jill    Skill2      Yes       "Rice"     abc      cba
Will    Skill3      Yes       "Dishes"   xyz      zyx
Phil    Skill3      No        n/a        123      321
Jill    Skill3      Yes       "Painting" abc      cba
```

I've done simpler conversions from wide to long, but this one has me stumped. I imagine there's a simple solution already on the forums but I have hit a wall and just need to ask for help!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more direct way to doing this but here is one way,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_cols(df %>% 
            select(-contains('text')) %>% 
            gather(skillname, YesOrNo, -1), 
         df %>% select(contains('text')) %>% 
            gather(var, text) %>% 
            select(-var)
          )
```

which gives,

> ```
>   Name skillname YesOrNo     text
> 1 Will    Skill1     Yes      SQL
> 2 Phil    Skill1     Yes      C++
> 3 Jill    Skill1      No      n/a
> 4 Will    Skill2      No      n/a
> 5 Phil    Skill2     Yes     Soup
> 6 Jill    Skill2     Yes     Rice
> 7 Will    Skill3     Yes   Dishes
> 8 Phil    Skill3      No      n/a
> 9 Jill    Skill3     Yes Painting
> ```

To address your new requirements,

```
bind_cols(df %>%
            select(-matches('text|comm')) %>%
            gather(skillname, YesOrNo, -1),
         df %>% select(contains('text')) %>%
            gather(var, text) %>%
            select(-var),
         df %>%
          select(contains('comm')) %>%
          mutate_all(list(function(i) strsplit(toString(i), ', '))) %>%
          unnest()
          )
```

which gives,

> ```
>   Name skillname YesOrNo     text Comm1 Comm2
> 1 Will    Skill1     Yes      SQL   xyz   zyx
> 2 Phil    Skill1     Yes      C++   123   321
> 3 Jill    Skill1      No      n/a   abc   cba
> 4 Will    Skill2      No      n/a   xyz   zyx
> 5 Phil    Skill2     Yes     Soup   123   321
> 6 Jill    Skill2     Yes     Rice   abc   cba
> 7 Will    Skill3     Yes   Dishes   xyz   zyx
> 8 Phil    Skill3      No      n/a   123   321
> 9 Jill    Skill3     Yes Painting   abc   cba
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much Sotos, with minor modification I was able to use your solution! I did encounter a problem, I was given a new dataset with additional columns of string data I want to add to the tall dataset. I've been playing around with modifying your code, but haven't quite figured it out. Would you be willing to take a look at the edited version of my challenge above?

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: So I gave this version of the code a try; the edited version as suggested above. I'm getting this error:

**Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace**

I thought this might be due to NA values present in the data frame, so tried labeling all NA in different ways, but am getting the same result. I'll keep chipping away at it but would love any input.

Comment: I can not help you any further unless you post the data that replicates that error so I can run it from my end.

Comment: Thanks Sotos! I'll anonymize the dataset and post it. This is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it thanks to function `tidyr::pivot_longer()` available from *tidyr 1.0.0* :

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'rvest':
#>   method            from
#>   read_xml.response xml2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.1

df <- read.table(h=T, strin=F, text='Name    Skill1 Skill1text   Skill2  Skill2text  Skill3  Skill3text Comm1 Comm2
Will    Yes    "SQL"        No      n/a         Yes     "Dishes"   xyz   zyx
Phil    Yes    "C++"        Yes     "Soup"      No      n/a        123   321
Jill    No     n/a          Yes     "Rice"      Yes     "Painting" abc   cba')

df %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^Skill\\d$")), paste0,"YesOrNo") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -c(1,starts_with("Comm")), 
    names_to = c("Skill",".value"), 
    names_pattern = "(Skill\\d+)(.*)")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#>   Name  Comm1 Comm2 Skill  YesOrNo text    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
#> 1 Will  xyz   zyx   Skill1 Yes     SQL     
#> 2 Will  xyz   zyx   Skill2 No      n/a     
#> 3 Will  xyz   zyx   Skill3 Yes     Dishes  
#> 4 Phil  123   321   Skill1 Yes     C++     
#> 5 Phil  123   321   Skill2 Yes     Soup    
#> 6 Phil  123   321   Skill3 No      n/a     
#> 7 Jill  abc   cba   Skill1 No      n/a     
#> 8 Jill  abc   cba   Skill2 Yes     Rice    
#> 9 Jill  abc   cba   Skill3 Yes     Painting
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We first rename the Yes/No columns to have a consistent format, then we use the special value `.value` in `pivot_longer()` to move the skill to its own column